# Does Cubase always assume music is tuned in 440 for VariAudio (or other stuff)?

Tags: cubase

The title says it all

Does Cubase always assume music is tuned in 440 for VariAudio (or other stuff)?
Can that be changed?

Is there any tool (free or built-in) to analyse the tuning frequency of an audio file?

"How" standard is it? Alternatively, to what extent I assume that all pouplar, western, not-a-century-old, audio tracks are tuned in 440Hz?

Thanks for you help

Comment: a quick google search answerred your question:
http://forum.recordingreview.com/f23/can-you-change-tuning-project-cubase-i-e-midi-48088/

Comment: @ArnoudTraa, yes, I had seen that. One guy says "I am unaware of a way", referring specifically to MIDI tracks, while another one says that anything can be done. Then one guy says that 440 is the standard for VariAudio. Finally, that 432 has also been a used standard. I don't feel it answers everything clearly and have higher hopes. Thanks for the link, it's useful

Comment: At least, I am hoping for a good workaround to working with an audio track whose exact tuning I am not certain. If nothing can be done with the settings, the track could manually transposed to 440Hz, but how do I know exactly how much it needs to be transposed?

Comment: ok, maybe next time mention that you have tried searching the internet. this helps us anwer you. have you asked on steinbergs own forum? there's a very resourceful community.

Comment: @ArnoudTraa, yes, should have mentioned. No, I haven't crossposted this anywhere yet. If I do I'll add a link here so noone wastes their time.